# No animations on ubuntu gnome

Tags: gnome, 15.04, animations

I am trying to install an ubuntu gnome distro but every time I live boot or install I get no animations at all.

I tried ubuntu 15.04.

Here are my specs

```
I5 - 4690K
MSI GTX - 970
12 GB DDR3
```

Here is a video I recorded to show my problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6U6uJotddI&feature=youtu.be

Please help me with this issue so I could use ubuntu on my desktop.

Comment: @DavidFoerster after

Comment: Here is a video showing my problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6U6uJotddI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Great example video! +1